# Custom url generator class

Tags: symfony

I am looking for a way to override the generation of the url for a specific route in Symfony2.
In symfony 1.4 I used to do it like this:

```
RouteName:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                Model
    prefix_path:          /route/:id/:slug
    column:               id
    route_class:          CustomDoctrineRoute
```

---

```
class CustomDoctrineRoute extends sfDoctrineRoute
{
  public function generate($params, $context = array(), $absolute = false)
  {
    //custom logic on route params

    return parent::generate($params, $context, $absolute);
  }

}
```

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9016324/219931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite core Router class path:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="router.class">Company\Bundle\Router\CustomRouter</parameter>
</parameters>
```

Default Router class (Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router) have default options (see method setOptions()), you can set them in your app parameters and overwrite needed class, instead all Router:

```
router.options.generator_class:  Company\Bundle\Router\UrlGenerator
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: When I used this solution, I had to do "router.options.generator_base_class" in order to get it to work.  But the solution did point me in the right direction.  Just reference the FrameworkBundle's routing.xml

Comment: @KSolo I'm trying to get this working, but not sure what I have to do. I have rounting.yml file and config.yml. can you point me to right direction please. I have already created the class, just need to set router.options.generator_base_class path