# Symfony 2: how to route based both on the host and URI?

Tags: symfony, routes

As [Yahoo points this out](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free), I would like to be able to do two things:

- resolve route in the front controller using both URI **and** host
- when creating/using templates, return not "relative" routes (like `'/img/st.jpg'`) but full routes (like `'//s1.mysite.com/st.png'`) and more: increment counter (=> next static link should be like `'//s`**2**`.mysite.com/whatever.png'`)
- an to go further, i'd like to include the language (like `'//s1.`**us**`.mysite.com/st.png'` and `'//s1.`**fr**`.mysite.com/st.png'`)

How would you do this? I could easily do Apache rules like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.((([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.)+)([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.(fr|com|net|org|eu)$
RewriteRule BLABLABLABLA
```

I dont go further here but I've got no problem about RewriteRules. The problem is about constructing the Web page with right "optimized" URLs in it. How would you do this?

If I'm not clear enough, I'm sorry, so I'll give you a real sample: I'd like to transform this code:

```
<img src="/p/s/pizza.png" alt="aaa" />
<div class="img-large">
    <img src="/l/l/pizza.png" alt="bbb" />
</div>
```

to

```
<img src="http://fr.s2.partner.mysite.fr/p/s/pizza.png" alt="aaa" />
<div class="img-large">
    <img src="http://fr.s3.partner.mysite.fr/p/l/pizza.png" alt="bbb" />
</div>
```

(I did not write Twig template code to stay as clear as possible).
How would you do this?

Comment: From Symfony 2.3 onwards you will be able to do this natively, as explained on this pull request: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the routing generator. I would say add an additional parameter named hostname lets say to the generateRoute method. A simple example of how to override the routing generator is given below:

[Custom url generator class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853020/custom-url-generator-class)
and
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

Then you can create a custom Twig tag to use specifically for static assets where you can invoke the new generateRoute method, setting up the new custom parameter called hostname using whatever strategy you want (random, based on some kind of incrementing logic (maybe using a session)). Thats just proof of concept and will require some googling and reading of docs but there is no reason why it shouldnt work...

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2.2 supports routing by Host: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

If you are using Symfony 2.1 or below, you can't use subdomains for routing per se, but you can set up a listener to do something on the page load based on the sub domain.

Example listener:

```
#config.yml
services:        
  myListener:
    class: myApp\MyBundle\Controller\MyListener
    arguments: 
        container: "@service_container"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 64 }



class MyListener extends controller
{

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }    

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {       
        $currentHost = $request->getHost();
        // do something, i.e set the language
    }

}
```

Comment: You're saying that it's not possible to generate a kindof "rotating" static domain URI's like I did on my own framework here: http://remy.livrepizzas.fr/ (it's just a sample, I know the web page is ugly, but right click to see source HTML code)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but let's say you want to set the language, or a company/user specific setting based on a unique subdomain you could use a listener to achieve that, basically it runs before your bundle, so you get the URL, set a session var then run your app, if that makes sense? I just included a basic (untested) example

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I didn't express myself properly. The problem is not "analyzing the host" when client wants to read a page, but when the server *generates* the page: I'd like to "know" when there are static elements, and if so, generate specific URI like the ones I described in my question. Sorry again if I don't express myself properly.

Comment: Symfony 2.2 will support routing by host name, if that helps you? http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html